# Is need to create a provisioning certificate for each iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I want to know , Is need to create each provisioning certificate for each iOS app.

Or one provisioning is enough for all of apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is enough for development purposes and even for distribution, if you don't use In-App, Push and iCloud. Otherwise you need one provision for each app.

Comment: So is need to get distribution privisioning certificate to distribute too?And What is iOS team provisioning certificate that created by XCodes?

Comment: Yes to publish on the app store, with ad-hoc or in-house (if you subscribed the enterprise development program) you need at least two provisioning profiles, one for development and one for distribution.

Comment: The iOS team provisioning profile from Xcode is just for development and includes every device you added through organizer (when clicked to use for development) to a wildcard certificate (suitable for every application id).